# Transpose rows to columns in Excel using formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following table of results that i would like to transpose from rows to columns using formulas.

```
Name        Details         Values
Server1     CPU             1
Server1     Cores           4
Server1     Memory          16
Server2     Disk1           100
Server2     Memory          8
Server2     OS              Windows 2012
```

The results should look like

```
Name       CPU       Cores      Memory      Disk1     OS
Server1    1         4          16                     
Server2                         8            100       Windows 2012
```

Is there a way to do this using formulas and not macros?

Comment: You could use a pivot table and then vlookup the remaining text values .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make a helper column in source table: `=$A2&$B2`. I.e. concatenate server and details columns.
2. Use `VLOOKUP` to get data into destination table: `=VLOOKUP($A2&B$1,<source_range>,<values_column_number>,FALSE)`.
3. If you need to hide errors: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2&B$1,<source_range>,<values_column_number>,FALSE),"")`.

[image]

**NOTE:** Unfortunately, you have to prepare list of servers and properties manually.